# How can i see dropdown button in realtime

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

My problem is i can not see realtime strings which are selected by me, in realtime.
For instance, if i choose one string from dropdrown items, then i can not see it. If i want to see it, first i have to go back and open the form again. How can i solve this ?
(By the way, it works, there is no problem about submit button. I just want to see what is user choose.

my problem:
[image]

my codes:

```
Widget dropdownButton(BuildContext context) {
    String constantValue = "League Of Legends";
    return DropdownButton(
        value: context.read<PostProvider>().postCategory ?? constantValue,
     
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          context.read<PostProvider>().postCategory = newValue;
     
        },
        items: <String>["League Of Legends", "Steam", "Csgo"]
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            onTap: () => context.read<PostProvider>().postCategory,
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList());
  }






String get postCategory => _postCategory;

  set postCategory(String value) {
    _postCategory = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

and also PostProvider extends changenotifier:

```
String get postCategory => _postCategory;

  set postCategory(String value) {
    _postCategory = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

homepage:

```
Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: CreatePostButton(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text("Home Page"),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    provider.logout();
                  },
                  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.poo))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: HomePageWidget())
```

create post button:

```
class CreatePostButton extends StatelessWidget {
  static final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: '_formKey');
  static final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0, bottom: 13.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(context: context, child: buildAlertDialog(context));
            }),
      );

  Widget buildAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<PostProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                      autocorrect: true,
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                      enableSuggestions: false,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length <= 4) {
                          return 'Please enter at least 4 characters';
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Post Title'),
                      onChanged: (postTitle) {
                        provider.postTitle = postTitle;
                      })),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                      autocorrect: true,
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                      enableSuggestions: false,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length <= 25) {
                          return 'Please enter at least 25 characters';
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      decoration:
                          InputDecoration(labelText: 'Write a post details'),
                      onChanged: (postDetails) {
                        provider.postDetails = postDetails;
                      })),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                      enableSuggestions: false,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length >= 4) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid value';
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter the Price'),
                      onChanged: (gamePrice) {
                        provider.gamePrice = gamePrice;
                      })),
              dropdownButton(context),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Submit"),
                    onPressed: () => submitNewPost(context)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future submitNewPost(BuildContext context) async {
    final provider = Provider.of<PostProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      final isSuccess = await provider.createNewPost();

      if (isSuccess) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      } else {
        final message = 'An error occurred, please check your inputs!';

        Center(child: Text(message),);
      }
    }
  }

  Widget dropdownButton(BuildContext context) {
    String constantValue = "League Of Legends";
    return DropdownButton(
        value: context.read<PostProvider>().postCategory ?? constantValue,
     
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          context.read<PostProvider>().postCategory = newValue;
     
        },
        items: <String>["League Of Legends", "Steam", "Csgo"]
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            onTap: () => context.read<PostProvider>().postCategory,
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be because you only update the screen upon clicking the submit button and not on closing the dialog. You can wait for the dialog to pop and reload the state of the page.

Comment: @javachipper but my code(above) already has it is. Look at the dropdownmenu item onTap function. What should i do

Comment: Can you post the code of your home page?

Comment: @javachipper of course. I editted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your dropdown button with a consumer to update the widget:

```
    Widget dropdownButton(BuildContext context) {
                String constantValue = "League Of Legends";
                
    
       return Consumer<PostProvider>(builder: (_context, _postprovider, _widget) { 
             return DropdownButton(
                    value: _postprovider.postCategory  ?? constantValue,
                 
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      _postprovider.postCategory = newValue;
                 
                    },
                    items: <String>["League Of Legends", "Steam", "Csgo"]
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        onTap: () => context.read<PostProvider>().postCategory,
                        value: value ?? constantValue,
                        child: Text(value ?? constantValue),
                      );
                    }).toList());
              });
      }
```

Here add this:

```
 Future submitNewPost(BuildContext context) async {
    final provider = Provider.of<PostProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    if (isValid) {
       if( provider.postCategory == null || provider.postCategory.isEmpty){
         provider.postCategory = "League Of Legends";
       } 

      _formKey.currentState.save();

      final isSuccess = await provider.createNewPost();

      if (isSuccess) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      } else {
        final message = 'An error occurred, please check your inputs!';

        Center(child: Text(message),);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: hello again. I solved this problem but still there is one problem. You wrote value: _postprovider ?? constantValue,
I changed this to value: _postprovider.postCategory ?? constantValue, its okey. But constantvalue is not working.If i do not choose any value, it gives this: 
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'

what should i do ? Yes constanvalue is seems but just seems. I want to if i do not choose any value, it choose constantvalue automatically

Comment: I updated my answer above for the null values

Comment: i tried but it gives same error i do not know why. Actually your code is good but why it does not work.

A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'

Comment: when do you exactly encounter that error? after choosing from the dropdown or after submitting / clicking on the submit button?

Comment: clicking on the submit button, so after post exactly

Comment: check the edits, if it still persists then its outside the widget. You might want to check your homewidget

Comment: Thanks a lot i solved with your last code! Happy new year...